# CensOSのfirewalldを起動後、ログインできなくなってしまった。

Tags: centos, ssh, conoha

CentOSのfirewalldを設定するために、

```
systemctl start firewalld.service
```

で起動しました。

その後、誤ってサーバーからログアウトしてしまいました。

ssh接続でログインしようとするも、

```
ssh: connect to host 118.27.xx.xx port 10022: Connection refused
```

という表示が出て接続できません。

firewalldを停止しようにも、サーバーにログインできないので詰んでいる状況です。

なにか打開策はあるでしょうか？

ちなみにサーバーはVPSのConoHaを使っています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コントロールパネルから「コンソール」ログインを試してください。

https://www.conoha.jp/guide/console.php

Comment: ありがとうございます。助かりました。